# Elasticsearch additional boost if multiple conditions are met

Tags: elasticsearch

Imagine I have a document, which looks like this:

```
{
  "Title": "Smartphones in United Kingdom",
  "Text": "A huge text about the topic",
  "CategoryTags": [
    {
      "CategoryID": 1,
      "CategoryName": "Smartphone"
    },
    {
      "CategoryID": 2,
      "CategoryName": "Apple"
    },
    {
      "CategoryID": 3,
      "CategoryName": "Samsung"
    }
  ],
  "GeographyTags": [
    {
      "GeographyID": 1,
      "GeographyName": "Western Europe"
    },
    {
      "GeographyID": 2,
      "GeographyName": "United Kingdom"
    }
  ]
}
```

`CategoryTags` and `GeographyTags` are stored as nested subdocuments.

I'd be looking for "apple united kingdom" in my search bar. How'd I make a query that would boost this document if it has both matching category and geography at the same time?

I was thinking of [multi_match](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) query, but I didn't figure out how would I deal with nested documents here...

I was thinking of nesting must into should statement. Would that make any sense?

```
POST /_search
{
  "template": {
    "size": "50",
    "_source": {
      "include": "Title"
    },
    "query": {
      "filtered": {
        "query": {
          "bool": {
            "minimum_number_should_match": "2<50%",
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "Text": {
                    "query": "{{SearchPhrase}}"
                  }
                }
              }
            ],
            "should": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "Title": {
                    "query": "{{SearchPhrase}}",
                    "type": "phrase",
                    "boost": "20"
                  }
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "CategoryTags",
                        "query": {
                          "match": {
                            "CategoryTags.CategoryName": "{{SearchPhrase}}"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "nested": {
                        "path": "GeographyTags",
                        "query": {
                          "match": {
                            "GeographyTags.GeographyName": "{{SearchPhrase}}"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want the boost to be added only if BOTH nested clauses are met,  that should do the job pretty well. Congrats :)

Comment: Perhaps there's an easier and cleaner way on doing that?

Comment: As it is, I hardly know how to make a shorter query. It's the problem with the Query DSL in JSON : it's quickly verbose, but imho, your query is already quite lean. A `multi_match` won't make it as it won't generate nested queries.

Comment: Thanks for your input @ThomasC